# javascript/AJAX not working in safari not bubbling through to body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, safari

I have a php/javascript/ajax code which allows adding, updating and deleting of records it all works fine on my laptop. If I try to use it on my phone the adding and deleting of records works but the update does not. In order for a record to update a div is moved to make the form boxes underneath visible. I think I'm having trouble with the click and blur event handlers. I'm very new to Javascript and have looked at some tutorials about using the console to find the error but I don't know where to start. The portion of code that I think is causing the problem is:

```
// Show the text box on click
    $('body').delegate('.editable', 'click', function(){
        var ThisElement = $(this);
        ThisElement.find('span').hide();
        ThisElement.find('.gridder_input').show().focus();
    });
```

and once this is fixed I'm worried that the following may stick too:

```
// Pass and save the textbox values on blur function
    $('body').delegate('.gridder_input', 'blur', function(){
        var ThisElement = $(this);
        ThisElement.hide();
        ThisElement.prev('span').show().html($(this).val()).prop('title', $(this).val());
        var UrlToPass = 'action=update&value='+ThisElement.val()+'&crypto='+ThisElement.prop('name');
        if(ThisElement.hasClass('datepicker')) {
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url : 'activities_ajax.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : UrlToPass
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an `error` handler to the AJAX call so you can diagnose the issue?

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down - delegate is not operating correctly on iOS safari - it does not bubble through to the body. I've tried playing with pointer and cursor in the css but that hasn't fixed it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer. It's only delegating to the body that doesnt work so I added a div wrapper around everything and delegated to that instead of the body.